# Use URLLIB without system default proxy Python

Tags: python, proxy, overriding, urllib

I have a small script that needs to communicate with me, it is part of my proxy. The script needs to run before the proxy starts, but the system is set to use the proxy, so it does not go through. How would I use urllib, but not the default proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[urllib docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html):

> ```
> urllib.urlopen(url[, data[, proxies]])
> ```
>
> [...]
>   Alternatively, the optional proxies argument may be used to explicitly specify proxies. It must be a dictionary mapping scheme names to proxy URLs, where an empty dictionary causes no proxies to be used, and None (the default value) causes environmental proxy settings to be used as discussed above. [...]

So just use `proxies={}`.